# No connectivity between clients on the same interface

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I'm having a problem configuring wireless interfaces in Linux. For some reason, traffic generated by wireless clients destined for other wireless clients on the same interface gets dropped (i.e. arp requests, icmp, the likes).

For example, 10.0.1.2 (connected to wlan0) can ping 10.0.1.3 (connected to wlan1) and vice versa. However, 10.0.1.4 (also connected to wlan1) cannot ping 10.0.1.3.

Interestingly, wireshark shows the incoming packets, so they are reaching the interface. I currently have the wireless interface attached to a bridge, however the problem also occurs without the bridge. I've also tried various wireless chips with various clients and they all behave the same way. Also, adding the relevant arp records manually on the wireless clients does not fix the problem.

To me, this seems like some sysctl or ip route setting I've missed. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any particular part of my config.

For reference, ap_isolate is not set in my hostapd config and the only sysctl param I have specified is net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1, with NAT configured in iptables.

UPDATE 1 (relevant sysctl config):

```
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.accept_source_route = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.drop_gratuitous_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wls15.tag = 0
```

Looks like enabling redirection fixed the issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the configuration settings for the wireless device.  The command `sysctl -a | grep ipv4.conf.wlan0` should give the settings.  These are the settings I have configured:

```
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.accept_source_route = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlan0.shared_media = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! No luck though. I've updated my post with the relevant lines from sysctl (after applying your config).

Comment: So it looks like that made somewhat of a difference (see update)...

Comment: check two thinks, the iptables, can try by flushing iptables if you are not much familiar with rules and also check  gw for wan1..

Comment: Flushing the arp tables on all clients resolved the issue once redirection was enabled. Thanks for the help!